# why optimization does not happen?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-construction

I have C/C++ code, that looks like this:

```
static int function(double *I) {
    int n = 0;
    // more instructions, loops,
    for (int i; ...; ++i)
        n += fabs(I[i] > tolerance);
    return n;
}

function(I); // return value is not used.
```

compiler inlines function, however it does not optimize out `n` manipulations.
I would expect compiler is able to recognize that value is never used as rhs only.
Is there some side effect, which prevents optimization?

compiler does not seem to matter, I tried Intel and gcc.  Aggressive optimization,  `-O3`

Thanks

fuller code (full code is repetition of such blocks):

```
  280         // function registers
  281         double q0 = 0.0;
  282         double q1 = 0.0;
  283         double q2 = 0.0;
  284
  285 #if defined (__INTEL_COMPILER)
  286 #pragma vector aligned
  287 #endif // alignment attribute
  288         for (int a = 0; a < int(N); ++a) {
  289             q0 += Ix(a,1,0)*Iy(a,0,0)*Iz(a,0,0);
  290             q1 += Ix(a,0,0)*Iy(a,1,0)*Iz(a,0,0);
  291             q2 += Ix(a,0,0)*Iy(a,0,0)*Iz(a,1,0);
  292         }
  293 #endif // not SSE
  294
  295         //contraction coefficients
  296         qK0 += q0*C[k+0];
  297         qK1 += q1*C[k+0];
  298         qK2 += q2*C[k+0];
  299
  300         Ix += 3*dim2d;
  301         Iy += 3*dim2d;
  302         Iz += 3*dim2d;
  303
  304     }
  305     Ix = Ix - 3*dim2d*K;
  306     Iy = Iy - 3*dim2d*K;
  307     Iz = Iz - 3*dim2d*K;
  308
  309     // normalization, scaling, and storage
  310     if(normalize) {
  311         I[0] = scale*NORMALIZE[1]*NORMALIZE[0]*(qK0 + I[0]);
  312         num += (fabs(I[0]) >= tol);
  313         I[1] = scale*NORMALIZE[2]*NORMALIZE[0]*(qK1 + I[1]);
  314         num += (fabs(I[1]) >= tol);
  315         I[2] = scale*NORMALIZE[3]*NORMALIZE[0]*(qK2 + I[2]);
  316         num += (fabs(I[2]) >= tol);
  317     }
  318     else {
  319         I[0] = scale*(qK0 + I[0]);
  320         num += (fabs(I[0]) >= tol);
  321         I[1] = scale*(qK1 + I[1]);
  322         num += (fabs(I[1]) >= tol);
  323         I[2] = scale*(qK2 + I[2]);
  324         num += (fabs(I[2]) >= tol);
  325     }
  326
  327
  328     return num;
```

my only guess is potentially floating-point exceptions, which introduced side effects

Comment: Which compiler, what optimisation flags?

Comment: Please put the `...` piece into your code. It may be important.

Comment: Can you post a complete version that shows the problem? If I fill in the loop to run from, say, `i=0` to `i=10000` and call it from an otherwise empty `main` gcc seems to optimize everything away (except for an adjustment of the stack pointer back and forth - not sure why it leaves this :))

Comment: MSVC10 doesn't even do that, it just completely skips the function code, the call and the array initialization, leaving an empty `main` function. I agree that we need more code.

Comment: @Mike try `-fomit-frame-pointer`

Comment: @Blindy: Yeah, it must be something in the other code... unless the OP has an old version of gcc?? (Also, I've now checked with gcc 4.5 and it doesn't have the stack pointer stuff - the assembly is identical if the call is commented out, like MSVC10).

Comment: @Johannes Ah, that fixed it!  Is there a reason for leaving it in by default?  (It's two instructions, one that subtracts 4 from `esp`, then one immediately after that adds 4 to it).

Comment: @Mike afaik it's mainly for debugging. So GDB knows the start of the stack-frame by reading the frame-pointer, instead of having to read the instructions before the instruction pointer to see how much stack was pushed when the function started. Therefor, if you use `alloca`, frame pointers are required.

Comment: As an side, you probably want `fabs(I[i]) > tolerance`, not `fabs(I[i] > tolerance)`.  The former checks to see if the absolute value of I[i] is greater than the tolerance, and the latter tests the signed value and does an unnecessary `fabs()` on 0 or 1.

Comment: Why are you taking fabs of the result of a comparison that will be 0 or 1? Copy-paste error?

Comment: @aaa: Frankly, I don't see how your new code is similar to the old one. Where is the problematic cycle in the new code? Where's is the inlined function?

Comment: @Andrey you are right, I posted snippet hoping someone may see something obvious. cycle is basically unrolled. did not want to put too much code, my bad

Comment: I'm probably alone in this, but that's the kind of optimization I have no use for and I wish people would not be led to expect. Do people write tricky code just to see if the compiler's smart enough *not* to compile it? If I write something like that, I would rather if the compiler did anything, it should give me a stern warning.

Answer (score 7):

The code does use `n`, first when it initializes it to 0 and then inside the loop on the left hand side of a function with possible side effects (`fabs`).

Whether or not you actually use the *return* of the function is irrelevant, `n` itself *is* used.

Update: I tried this code in MSVC10 and it optimized the whole function away. Give me a full example I could try.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

const int tolerance=10;

static int function(double *I) {
    int n = 0;
    // more instructions, loops,
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        n += fabs((double)(I[i] > tolerance));
    return n;
}


int main()
{
    double I[]={1,2,3,4,5};

    function(I); // return value is not use
}
```

Comment: yes, but n is only used with respect to itself, it is not used as a right-hand value in any of expressions.  I would expect compiler to recognize that

Comment: After inlining, the code looks like `int n = 0; for(...) n+=...;`. `n` is not used anymore after that loop. It could produce the possible side effects of `fabs` without using storage for `n`, if i'm not missing something. It could even know about `fabs` (see `-fno-builtin`), and optimize out the entire loop. But apparently it doesn't do that.

Comment: To elaborate: Even though it's inlined, the compiler has to generate just one version of `function`, and if it generated a version that didn't return anything, you would never actually be able to call it when you DID need the return value.

Comment: @Potato: Maybe, maybe not. You can't really assume that.

Comment: @Mark B: The OP appears to be inspecting the inlined code, not the version that was generated with a body. Why `n` was not removed from inlined code is indeed not clear. Apparently, the compiler was not smart enough. Also, compilers will not normally generate a standalone body for an inlined function if the function does not explicitly *require* a body (like called through a pointer, for example)

Comment: @Johannes: The way I see it, `n` is used in the return, you just choose to ignore the value in this case. You may use it in the future or not, the compiler doesn't know (or it wouldn't if `static` wasn't used). I agree that an insanely aggressive optimizer could remove this, but it seems like it's too much work for gcc's current implementation.

Comment: GCC is optimizing like mad. This sounds like a simple job for it.

Comment: @Blindy: The compiler *does* know that the return value is not used when the function call is *inlined*, as OP explicitly stated.

Comment: @I could try to isolate full function, but the actual function is rather complex part of library. may take me some time to do so

Comment: I've seen that kind of very agresssive optimizations in VS2008 / 2010, even across compilation units. It's damn impressive! Makes it a little bit harder to write "appropriate" performance test routines, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer to this question is, just because a compiler *can* make some optimization in theory doesn't mean that it *will*.  Nothing comes for free.  If the compiler is going to optimize away n, then someone has to write the code to do it.

That sounds like a lot of work for something that is both a bizarre corner case and a trivial space savings.  I mean, how often do people write functions that perform complex calculations only to discard the result?  Is it worth writing complex optimizations to recover 8 bytes worth of stack space in such cases?

Comment: Given the recently posted code, this is probably the correct answer.  Compilers aren't magic machines.

Comment: In the general case, it isn't that uncommon.  A function might generate two return values, only one of which you actually care about.  Or the actual work of the function could be completely orthogonal to the return value; a function that builds an array, for instance, and returns the number of values in the array.  If you don't care about the number of values in the array, so long as the array got built, then you might ignore the return value outright.

Comment: I agree that it's quite routine to ignore return values. But in such cases, the return value is usually trivial, as in your array example. That means you'd get a small savings by optimizing it away. The code to do that optimization, however, would be complex.

Comment: @peter I thought unnecessary code path will be presented as parse tree not connected to anything, which compiler just drops.it seems like a pretty common scenario

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but without being privy to the internal workings of the compilers you used, I can't comment further.

Comment: Often is isn't a question of the return value not being used, but detecting if the act of calling the function generates side effects that must be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain that it will have an effect, but you may want to look into GCC's `pure` and `const` attribute (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). It basically tells the compiler that the function only operates on its input and has no side effects.

Given this extra information, it may be able to determine that the call is unnecessary.

Comment: they seem to have added more optimization options which may be useful to me.thanks

Comment: I would assume you want to put a const on the input function(const double *I) both for correctness and perhaps it helps the compiler optimize, dont know till you try.

Comment: @dweltch: while you are correct in giving that advice. I was actually referring to a GCC **attribute** named `const`. See the link I posted for details.

Answer (score 0):

Despite arguments I have had in other threads where all compilers are perfect and never miss an optimization.  Compilers are not perfect and dont often catch optimizations.

Fun ones like this:

```
int fun ( int a )
{
   switch(a&3)
   {
      case 0: return(a+4); 
      case 1: return(a+2);
      case 2: return(a);
      case 3: return(0);
   }
   return(1);
}
```

For the longest time if you left that return at the end out you would get an error that the function defined a return type but failed to return a value.  Some compilers would complain with the return() at the end of the function and complain without it.

From what I can tell from gcc vs say llvm, gcc optimizes within a function within a file where llvm optimizes across all of what it is fed.  And you can join the bytecode for the entire project into one file and optimize the whole thing in one shot.   At the moment gcc output outperforms llvm by a dozen or more percent which is interesting.  give it time.

Perhaps in your case you are computing using two inputs that are not declared as static (const) so the result n could change.  If optimized on a per-function basis it cannot reduce it further.  So my guess is it is optimizing per function and the calling function doesnt know what affect the dynamic input I has on the system, even if the return value were not used it would still need to compute function(I) to resolve whatever is dependent on I.  I assume this is not an infinite loop, the ... means some limiting is imposed?  If not here again dynamic not static, function(I) could be a terminating infinite loop function or it could be there waiting for an interrupt service routine to modify I and kick it out of the infinite loop.